# Dropdown menu element increasing in height

Tags: html, css

So I drafted a design for input in word as below:

[image]

and I'm having issues in HTML where for some reason the second dropdown is following the height of the larger textarea height:

[image]

How do i make sure that the **second dropdown follows the height of the other dropdown** but **not follow the height of the textarea?**

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1vw;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
}

.input_field {
    margin-top: 1vh;
    display: flex;
}

.input_field_big {
    margin-top: 1vh;
    display: flex;
}

.dd {
    width: 35%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.in {
    margin-left: 7%;
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 4vh;
}

#summ_in {
    vertical-align: top;
    min-height: 18vh;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 7%;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href = "style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class = "input_field">
    <select id = "d1" name = "Name" class = "dd">
      <option value = "Name">Name</option>
    </select>
    <input type = "text" id = "name_in" class = "in" spellcheck="false">
  </div>
  <div class = "input_field_big">
    <select id = "d2" name = "Summary" class = "dd">
      <option value = "Summary">Summary</option>
    </select>
    <textarea id = "summ_in" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class = "input_field">
    <select id = "d3" name = "Stream" class = "dd">
      <option value = "Stream">Stream</option>
    </select>
    <input type = "text" id = "stream_in" class = "in" spellcheck="false">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, I'm open for recommendations on how to achieve this layout better as the current approach I'm using, I have to use a different class name for the second dropdown due to having a larger textarea, hence I find it weird having to do so.

Comment: Running the snippet shows that the two match in size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `align-items` is set to `stretch` in flexbox. So that select dropdown matches the height of textarea. To change that you can set the value to `flex-start`.

```
.input_field_big {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start; /* Pack flex items from the start */ 
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items

Answer (score 0):

Add `height: 4vh` to dropdown which is before textarea. select is trying to take the available height from the parent.